# Safari won't request video or audio from HTML 5 media elements?

Tags: html, safari, html5-video, html5-audio

So far what I've been developing has worked in Chrome and, using fallbacks, IE8.

What I don't get is this: Safari just won't start loading `<video>` or `<audio>` content.

[image: safari6]

Safari 6 won't load, and neither will iOS 5's Safari:

[image: ios5]

My code calls `.load()` on the elements at the appropriate time (at least for Chrome), so what gives?

Here is the video declaration:

```
<video width="800" height="600" class="faces" id="facesVideo">
  <source src="video/grid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="video/grid.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

The audio is declared dynamically, but has the same problem.

Do I need to wait for some DOM event that Chrome doesn't need before calling `.load()`?

What does it take to get Safari to start buffering until the elements can fire `canplaythrough`?

Comment: I should mention that my .htaccess is from HTML5 Boilerplate, so that probably isn't the problem.

Comment: Oh blerg, apparently `.load()` is "supported in all major browsers, except Safari": http://www.w3schools.com/html5/av_met_load.asp …so, what now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Safari does not support `.load()`, `preload="auto"` must be added to any HTML5 media elements that you want Safari to buffer before playing. Go figure.

i.e. the element should look like:

```
<video width="800" height="600" class="faces" id="facesVideo" preload="auto">
  <source src="video/grid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="video/grid.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

Comment: As a (important) side note: `preload="auto"` is absolutely ignored on iOS versions of Safari (see this page on [Safari HTML5 Audio and Video Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1))